# Using JavaScript Object value for clearRect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a canvas in which we can drag and drop the text. I'm trying to delete the last drawn text in the canvas like so..

```
$("#clear").click(function () {
  // calc the y coordinate for this text on the canvas              
  var obj = texts[texts.length-1];
  ctx.clearRect(obj.x,obj.y,obj.width,obj.height);
});
```

But when I click the button nothing seems to happen, no log/error in the console also.

NOTE: `texts` is the array in which all the text in the canvas are stored.

Comment: you're sure that `ctx` is set properly?

Comment: Please add the full code.

Comment: Can you share a JSFiddle or a working sample. Also as a side note, instead of  `var obj = texts[texts.length-1]` try `var obj = texts.pop()`. This will remove last item and return it

Comment: console your obj variable, is it having right object and is your ctx is defined in proper scope?

Comment: @Rajesh, Thanks Bud. pop() function worked :)